# `friend struct std::is_invocable` can't access private members of class it is friend to

Tags: c++, c++17, friend

I have made `struct std::is_invocable` be a `friend` of `class D`, but it is unable to access the private member of `D`.  This happens with gcc, clang,  and MS Visual Studio 2017, so it is not one of MSVC's quirks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

const double PI = 3.1415926535898;

class A
{
public:
    A(double xx) : x(xx)
    {
        s = sin(x);
    }
    
    double sinx()
    {
        return s;
    }
    
private:
    double x;
    double s;
};

class B
{
public:
    double sinx(double x)
    {
        return sin(x);
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    static double sinx(double x)
    {
        return sin(x);
    }
};

class D
{
private:
    double sinx(double x)
    {
        return sin(x);
    }
    
public:
    template<class T, class... Args>
    friend struct std::is_invocable;
};

class E
{
public:
    double sinx;
};

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    A a0(PI/2.);
    
    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&A::sinx), A&>::value << "\n";
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&B::sinx), B&, const double>::value << "\n";
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&B::sinx), const double>::value << "\n";
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&C::sinx), const double>::value << "\n";
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&D::sinx), D&, const double>::value << "\n";  // shouldn't this compile if 
                                                                                     // std::is_invocable is friend?
    cout << std::is_invocable<decltype(&E::sinx), E&, const double>::value << "\n";
    
    cout << "Press ENTER to exit.\n";
    std::getline(cin, s);
}
```

The error is:

> C2248 "'D::sinx': cannot access private member declared in class 'D'"

Why can't `std::is_invocable` access `D::sinx()`?

Comment: I'll bet you could remove at least 90% of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: You aren't in `std::is_invocable`.  You are in `main`, which is not a friend of your class.

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't `std::is_invocable` access `D::sinx()` ?

Because it isn't trying to. `main` is trying to access `D::sinx`. Which it can't. Remember: accessibility is about who can use the *name* of the member. You typed the name "D::sinx" in `main`. Therefore, it is `main` that is trying to access the name.

So you're giving access to the wrong thing.